# Windows Phone 7 and Sockets: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-7

So I set up a connection, everything is working great, and I start setting up code to read in packets from the server.  The way I want to structure it is with one packet identifier method, that reads a single byte (packet ID) and branches off to the appropriate method to read in the rest of it.  The problem lies in the last statement there - everything works until I branch off, when I get this exception:

> An asynchronous socket operation is already in progress using this SocketAsyncEventArgs instance.

Here's the general idea:

```
    private void IdentifyPacket(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Completed -= new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(IdentifyPacket);
        if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
        {
            ForceDisconnectWithError(new SocketErrorEventArgs(netSocket, e.SocketError));
            return;
        }

        PacketID packet = (PacketID)e.Buffer[0];

        switch (packet)
        {
            case PacketID.KeepAlive:
                e.SetBuffer(new byte[4], 0, 4);
                e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(HandleKeepAlive);
                e.ConnectSocket.ReceiveAsync(e);
                break;
            default:
                RelinkPacketManager();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void RelinkPacketManager()
    {
        socketConfig.SetBuffer(new byte[1], 0, 1);
        socketConfig.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(IdentifyPacket);
        netSocket.ReceiveAsync(socketConfig);
    }
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `Packet.KeepAlive`, do you send another request? Or just wait for more data to be received?
If you need to get the remaining bytes of data, you might already have it in the response in the bytes after `e.Buffer[0]`. 
So, instead of setting your buffer size before hand, you should try completely parse your response.

Hope that helps.

EDIT:
Try this

```
SocketAsyncEventArgs args;
switch (packet)
        {
            case PacketID.KeepAlive:
                args.SetBuffer(new byte[4], 0, 4);
                args.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(HandleKeepAlive);
                e.ConnectSocket.ReceiveAsync(args);
                break;
            default:
                RelinkPacketManager();
                break;
    }
```

Comment: e.Buffer's length is 1 when the IdenfityPacket method is run.

Comment: Well, what I meant to ask was, how is your response coming? Your response might be like this `[0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B]`, so when you take `e.Buffer[0]` you're skipping `0x0A` and `0x0B` even though the data that you need to collect is right after the first byte assuming `[0x01]` means `KeepAlive`.

Comment: I have working methods that use this system of "receive part, defer remainder" where all data is properly received.